# Python replacing characters selectively from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string which contains a fixed character. Can I generate a permutation of strings by replacing it with another character or string?? 
Say, I have something like this:

```
designatedstring="u"
replacerstring="ough"
s="thruput"
```

I want an output like:

```
l=["throughput","thrupought","throughpought"]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what happen if designated = u and the replace is uu, do you want the output the output of AuuA to have one  or two AuuuA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More `itertools` sugar:

```
>>> parts = s.split(designatedstring)
>>> num = len(parts) - 1
>>> replacements = itertools.product([designatedstring, replacerstring], repeat=num)
>>> replacements = list(replacements)
>>> replacements.remove((designatedstring,) * num)
>>> for r in replacements:
...     print ''.join(itertools.chain(*zip(parts, r + ('',))))
...
thrupought
throughput
throughpought
```

If you can bear with original string in the result, you can omit ugly transformations on 4 and 5 lines.

Comment: You have been faster than me for a few seconds! :o +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting way to do it, though I'd still go with the `itertools` solution.

Notice that the list of strings you produce is morally a binary tree: at each instance of the replacement character in the string you either want to ignore it ("go left") or replace it ("go right"). So you can make a binary tree structure out of the replacement strings. Walking the leaves of a binary tree is easy.

```
class ReplacementTree(object):
    def __init__(self, s, src, target, prefix=""):
        self.leaf = src not in s
        if 1 == len(s.split(src, 1)):
            self.head, self.tail = s, ""
        else:
            self.head, self.tail = s.split(src, 1)
        self.prefix, self.src, self.target = prefix, src, target

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.leaf:
            return self.prefix + self.head

    @property
    def left(self):
        if self.leaf:
            return None
        else:
            return ReplacementTree(self.tail, 
                                   self.src,
                                   self.target,
                                   prefix=self.prefix + self.head + self.src)

    @property
    def right(self):
        if self.leaf:
            return None
        else:
            return ReplacementTree(self.tail, 
                                   self.src,
                                   self.target,
                                   prefix=self.prefix + self.head + self.target)

def leaves(tree):
    if tree.leaf:
        yield tree.value
    else:
        for leaf in leaves(tree.left):
            yield leaf
        for leaf in leaves(tree.right):
            yield leaf
```

Example:

```
>>> x = repltree.ReplacementTree("thruput", "u", "ough")
>>> list(repltree.leaves(x))
['thruput', 'thrupought', 'throughput', 'throughpought']
```

Answer (score -1):

From the input given in your question, this will produce the list requested:

```
s="thruput"
designatedstring="u"
replacerstring="ough"

l = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == designatedstring:
        l += [s[:i] + replacerstring + s[i + 1:]]

l += [s.replace(designatedstring, replacerstring)]
```

Comment: @DrTyrsa It'll work, but it wont create the strings `'toughtoughtu'`, `'toughtutough'` and `'tutoughtough'`. Which technically wasn't specified in the question. ;)